# Magento 2.3 - Moving the payment option in the checkout to the first step

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, checkout, module, payment-gateway

Is there an easy way to move the payment options out of the second step (Payment and Review) and into the first step (Shipping Address)? I have searched far and wide and there is almost zero documentation on this particular issue, most people would suggest to use a one step checkout and I agree, but the for whatever reason the numbskull in charge is adamant on moving the payment after the shipping address on the same step.

Please advice

Answer (score 0):

In programming, everything is possible :)

You must search for <your_module_dir>/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

From there, you may edit the view as per your necessities.

If you decide to install the one step checkout extension, make sure the extension has the feature of allowing admin to change the orders as per your above necessity. Mine is from Magetop. Very good and reliable extension to now. And yes, mine allows me to change orders if I want.

Comment: Thanks! I'll start by checking that tomorrow when I'm back at the office :)